# Angular unique filter for nested ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, filter, unique

I wanted to insert the content so that it prints each students location next to a checkbox without having any duplicated locations. My HTML looks like this:

```
<ul ng-repeat="group in groups">
  <li ng-repeat="student in group.students | unique : 'location'">
     <input type="checkbox" id="location">
     <label for="location" ng-repeat="loc in student.location | unique : 'loc'">{{loc}}</label>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I am using this filter code to filter out repeated items in my JSON file.

App.js

```
app.filter('unique', function() {
    return function(input, key) {
        var uniqueList = [];
        var unique = {};
        for(var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
            if(typeof unique[input[i][key]] == "undefined") {
                unique[input[i][key]] = "";
                uniqueList.push(input[i]);

            }
        }
        return uniqueList;
    };
});
```

My JSON files is formatted like this :

```
"groups" : [
    {
        "name": "a",
        "students" : [
            {
                "student_name" : "Nate",
                "location" : "California"
            },
            {
                "student_name" : "Natalie",
                "location": "Michigan"
            },
            {
                "student_name" : "Tim",
                "location" : "California"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "name" : "b",
        "students" : [
            {
                "student_name" : "Brian",
                "location" : "California"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

It prints California Michigan California. I assume this is because the uniqueList resets when it enters another group. I am unsure how to go about this with nested objects. Can someone explain to me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Yes..it is indeed because you enter another group.

Comment: It is also helpful to note which version of angular you are using when asking questions, sometimes things are easier in a specific version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You won't be able to do this in a filter since you are correct each group resets it.  You will need to have something combine the groups before hand and then loop through the combined group.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'm not completely sure about the best approach to this issue is. I am thinking maybe to manually grab the JSON arrays and handle it all with vanilla javascript?

Comment: Angular 1.4 has a concept of merging which would be sufficient for your needs.  angular.merge(object1, object2);  https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.merge  however I am not sure what version you are on.  You could as your said just use vanilla js and combine the objects.

Comment: Thanks, I will definitely check it out!

Comment: @glocklesnar If this was a good answer for your could you flag as accepted answer otherwise let me know if you need any other help.